# Local hosted embeded video auto starting

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have been given a few videos to embed in a page using joomla but I am not familiar with the format. I need these to not auto play! I tried autostart:"0" autoplay:"0", also tried with false. any help is appreciated!
code below:

```
<a id='cnwebinarLink' href='http://cnpg.comparenetworks.com/187573-Discovering-volatile-biomarkers-using-GC-GC-TOFMS-Detecting-and-phenotyping-infections-directly-from-lung-samples/' data-keywords=‘Dr. Heather D. Bean discusses Discovering volatile biomarkers using GC×GC-TOFMS and Detecting and phenotyping infections directly from lung samples'>Webinar Permalink</a><script src='http://cnpg.comparenetworks.com/Media/29/Js/z.webinarAnalytics.js' type='text/javascript'></script><iframe width='985' height='675' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://cnpg.comparenetworks.com/187573-Discovering-volatile-biomarkers-using-GC-GC-TOFMS-Detecting-and-phenotyping-infections-directly-from-lung-samples/'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is that you're including a page from another site into yours. The problem here is that you can't set the autoplay value of the video player since this is not the same site.

And since there is not feature on the player to embed it, you can't do much.